# Determining the order of the kernel and image

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group.  Let $G'$ be a group and let $\phi : G \to G'$ be a homomorphism.  Let $K \leq G$ be the kernel of $\phi$ and $I \leq G'$ be the image of $\phi$.

(a)  Find a formula that relates the number of elements in $G$, $K$, and $I$.
(b)  Suppose $H \leq G$, Find a formula for the number of elements of $\phi(H)$.

I'm not sure if (a) is some sort of application of the Main Homomorphism Theorem or not.  I'm hoping to get some hints to sort of push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely an application of the first isomorphism theorem. If you can recall the statement, the formula should follow quickly.

Comment: So, $\frac{|G|}{|ker\phi|}|=|I|$.  But what about $b$?

Comment: By $H\leq G$, do you mean $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ or just a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Just a subgroup.  Nothing special.

Comment: $\phi\mid_H : H\to\phi(H)$ is surjective. Can you say anything about the kernel of $\phi\mid_H$?

Comment: Well, there is an isomorphism between $H/ker(\phi)\to \phi(H)$.  I believe this is similar to (a) then.

Comment: Be careful. $\phi : G\to G'$, so $\ker\phi$ might not be a subset of $H$ (for example, imagine that $\phi : G\to\{1\}$ sends every element of $G$ to $1$. Then $\ker\phi = G$, but for any proper subgroup $H$ of $G$, $\ker\phi\not\subseteq H$.

Comment: What if I restricted $\phi|_H$.  This way $\ker \phi|_H$ would only reflect what's going on between $H$ and $H'$.

Comment: $H/\ker\phi\mid_H\cong\phi(H)$. I assume they want you to express this in terms of (some of) the original given information, though. Is there a way you can write $\ker\phi\mid_H$ in terms of $K$ and $H$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to incorporate $K$ into this.  $K/H\cong \phi(H)$ was my first guess.  I'm trying to think of ways to shrink the excess out of the kernel.

Comment: Hint: if $x\in K$, then $x\in\ker\phi\mid_H$ iff $x\in H$.

Comment: I think I have it:  $H/(H\cap K)\cong \phi(H)$.